# gpg2 not able to download keys "receive failed: try again later"

Tags: networking, 20.04, gnupg

I'm attempting to add the keys for [RVM](https://rvm.io/), however, I am getting an error from gpg2.

```
$ gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Try again later
```

I've also tried a more verbose approach but I get the same error:

```
$ gpg2 -vvv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Try again later
```

Right now the only Google search for the exact error message I'm getting is from the Arch Linux support boards. [Here's the thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238918). It's a little terse and I'm not quiet able to follow it, but the symlink mentioned at the end of the settings is in place.

/etc/resolv.conf shows this

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Results of `resolvectl query keys.gnupg.net`

```
keys.gnupg.net: 209.244.105.201                -- link: enp37s0
                (hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net)

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 478.3ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

and `resolvectl status` says that my current DNS server is my router (Orbi model) 192.168.1.1. This is strange because when I load the Orbi app it says that the DNS servers are what I set them to which is 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 (unless Orbi proxies to them).

I've also tried some related Google searches and set my /root/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf and ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf (not sure if that one is required, but I thought it was worth a try) files to contain a one-line file that says standard-resolver and then `killall dirmngr`. This did not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: What's the output of `resolvectl query keys.gnupg.net`?

Comment: @KalebBurklow I've updated my original post with the output of that command

Comment: Your firewall may be preventing you from retrieving the keys, as the command attempts to make the connection on port 11371.  Ensure that port is open in iptables or try specifying port 80. `gpg2 -vvv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net:80 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`

Comment: @KalebBurklow specifying port 80 worked. Thanks! I'm not running iptables on my desktop. If I don't want to set it to port 80, will I have to set up a port forwarding rule on my router?

Comment: Port forwarding is only required when an IP outside of your local area establishes the connection.  You may have UFW running.  Try `sudo ufw allow 11371`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you're able to locate the server via DNS.  The default port utilized by key servers may be blocked by your firewall.  Attempt specifying port 80 as some key servers permit sending keys via over http.

```
gpg2 -vvv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net:80 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

You can also open the port for outbound and established inbound connections:

```
sudo ufw allow 11371
```

or

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 11371 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 11371  -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```